# SQL NOT IN operator to only return if all values are not in the set

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that will let me search if a patient has NOT received a medication. At first I thought that I could just do something like this:

```
INNER JOIN prescript p ON p.id = patient.id AND p.med_id NOT IN (5128)
```

Where `p.id` and `patient.id` signify the patient id, `p.med_id` refers to the medication id and `5128` is the medication being used in the query. The problem with this query is that if the patient has had other medications, those will show up. So if a patient has had medication 5128, but also another medication they will show up. But I only want to return a patient if they have not have that medication at all. The part that is tricky here is that I won't be able to know the patient id in any of this. So I need a solution that is similar to this:

```
INNER JOIN prescript p ON p.id = patient.id AND (SELECT med_id 
                                                 FROM prescript
                                                 WHERE id = p.pid) NOT IN (5128)
```

I was thinking that this might be possible if I could concatenate all of the med_id's into one string as well, but my problem with that is that I'm using a query builder so I'm limited to adding joins and adding wheres only. Aka I can't use `DECLARE`.

Comment: You should generally specify the SQL platform you are using (SQL Server, MySQL, etc) as there may be platform specific solutions to your issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM prescript WHERE id = patient.id AND med_id = 5128)` clause in your `WHERE` statement.

If you need to exclude a patient that has used at least one of a number of medications then you could use `med_id IN (5128, ...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Selected for simplicity. :)

Comment: *sigh*. subselect is not "simple"

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - If you have a simpler answer, I'm all ears. :)

Answer (score 3):

All patients who have not had medication 5128...

```
Select patient.*
from patient 
     left join prescript 
     on patient.id = prescript.patientid
     and prescript.medid = 5128
where 
     prescript.id is null
```

All patients who have not had medication 5128 or 3000

```
Select patient.*
from patient 
     left join prescript 
     on patient.id = prescript.patientid
     and prescript.medid in ( 5128 ,3000)
where 
     prescript.id is null
```

All patients who haven't had medication 5128 and 3000

```
Select patient.*
from patient 
     left join prescript 
     on patient.id = prescript.patientid         
     and prescript.medid in ( 5128 ,3000)           
group by patient.id, patient.name
having COUNT(distinct medid)<>2
```

Comment: Why do you have `where prescript.id is null`?

Comment: That excludes the people who have had the medication

Answer (score 1):

Try a `left join`:

```
left join prescript p on p.id = patient.id and med_id = 5128 where p.id is null
```

Comment: I tried `left join prescript p on p.id = patient.id and med_id in (5128) and p.id is null` and the patient who received that med still showed up.

Comment: @Aust That's because it's not what the answerer wrote.

Comment: @podiluska - Exactly. In my question I stated I needed to check if the values were in a set of med ids, `IN()` not if it was equal to a specific med id. `=`. So I figured that Paul assumed that it would work for both or else why would he post an answer that didn't answer my question? So I was just letting him know that it didn't work in the way that I needed it to.